# how to show multiple images in one tableview cell ios? i get images from webservices

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

```
(
    (
        "http://sportsromio.aiminfotechs.com/WEBSERVICES/available_sports/volleyball.png",
        "http://sportsromio.aiminfotechs.com/WEBSERVICES/available_sports/football.png"
    ),
(
    "http://sportsromio.aiminfotechs.com/WEBSERVICES/available_sports/football.png",
    "http://sportsromio.aiminfotechs.com/WEBSERVICES/available_sports/cricket.png"
)
```

I used this array how can I used it.

Comment: In the sample you show, you need to create a custom cell with two UIImageView...

Comment: if their are only two images you can have two imageviews, if they are more then that, you may see other options like image pager or collectionview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in **'cellForRowIndexPath'**

```
int x = 0;

        for (NSURL * url in yourArrayName) {
            UIImageView *yourImageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,50,20,20)];
            yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
            [cell addSubview:yourImageView];

            x = x + 60;
        }
```

Comment: Calling `dataWithContentsOfURL` on the main thread will block the thread until it completes as this is a synchronous method. Calling it in a loop is likely to create a very considerable lag and the app may even be killed.

Comment: Consider using `NSURLSession` for downloading the images in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

add in cell for Row

```
int x = 0;
    for (NSString * stringurl in [imgs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        UIImageView *yourImageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,10,40,40)];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:stringurl];

        __block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
        __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = yourImageView;

        [yourImageView sd_setImageWithURL:url
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]
                                   options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
                                  progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                                      if (!activityIndicator) {
                                          [weakImageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]];
                                          activityIndicator.center = weakImageView.center;
                                          [activityIndicator startAnimating];
                                      }
                                  }
                                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                     [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                                     activityIndicator = nil;
                                 }];


        [cell addSubview:yourImageView];

        x = x + 40;
    }
```